# Core Haptics not playing in iOS 15 with certain AVAudioSession configurations

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiosession, haptic-feedback

I'm using [Core Haptics](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corehaptics) to play a custom "heart beat" pattern, while simultaneously playing music using AVAudioPlayer. Specifically, I'm creating a simple `CHHapticPattern`, then creating a `CHHapticEngine` to play that pattern.

The custom haptics play just fine on an iPhone running iOS 14, but completely stopped working in iOS 15.0+. The haptic engine doesn't throw any errors in iOS 15, it just fails silently. Standard haptic feedback such as `UIImpactFeedbackGenerator` work just fine; it's just the custom haptics that fail.

After lots of debugging and seeing no obvious reasons why Core Haptics should suddenly stop working, I eventually discovered the culprit is that I have an `AVAudioSession` configured as follows:

```
     // Setup AVAudioSession
        do {
            
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: [.duckOthers]) // <-- This conflicts with Core Haptics on iOS 15, but not iOS 14
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            
        } catch {
            print("Error activating AVAudioSession: \(error)")
        }
```

If I remove the `.duckOthers` option (e.g., replace with `.mixWithOthers`), then the custom haptic pattern plays successfully in iOS 15 (and 14).

While I can live with using `.mixWithOthers` instead of `.duckOthers`, I can't see any obvious rationale why `.duckOthers` should conflict with Core Haptics, and suddenly start conflicting with it only in iOS 15.0+. Any ideas why? Otherwise I will file a bug report with Apple.

Here is a link to a stripped down, demo project demonstrating the issue. If you run it on iOS 15 on an iPhone that supports haptics (iPhone 8 or later), the custom haptic pattern doesn't play, but it plays just fine on iOS 14:  [link to project](https://github.com/WayneYHuang/Core-Haptics-iOS-15-Bug)

Answer (score 0):

You can set up your `CHHapticEngine` and set the property of `.playsHapticsOnly` to yes to avoid conflicting with AVAudioSession.